# How to keep background code running without create a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, pthreads

1. I am trying to build a simple UI with qt creator. Background code keep print a int flag and when user click on button, the flag changed, so the output changed.

**UI like this:**

[image]

**output like this: click 《output 1》， then change 0 to 1**

[image]

2. **How to keep background code running without create a thread in qt creator?**

here is the cpp code, I didnt add .h files:
all files are available here [jump to all code in github](https://github.com/jaysimon/clion_qtcreator)

#### main.cpp:

```cpp
    #include "MainWindow.h"
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <iostream>
    #include "deal.h"

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      std::cout << argc << " " << argv[0] << std::endl;
    //  getchar();
      QApplication a(argc, argv);

      MainWindow w;
      w.show();


    //  getchar();
      pthread_t tid;   //Not want to create a thread to run this
      pthread_create(&tid, NULL, run, NULL); 
      //pthread_exit(&tid);
      a.exec();
      return 0;
    }
```

#### MainWindow.cpp

```cpp
    #include "MainWindow.h"
    #include "ui_MainWindow.h"
    #include "deal.h"

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
      ui->setupUi(this);
      connect(ui->pbOriginSound, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(change2_origin_sound()));
      connect(ui->pbVecSound, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(change2_vec_sound()));
      connect(ui->pbVecNrSound, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(change2_vec_nr_sound()));
    }

    void MainWindow::change2_origin_sound(){
      iFlag = 0;
      printf("%d", iFlag);
    }

    void MainWindow::change2_vec_sound(){
      iFlag = 1;
      printf("%d", iFlag);
    }

    void MainWindow::change2_vec_nr_sound(){
      iFlag = 2;
      printf("%d", iFlag);
    }

    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
      delete ui;
    }
```

#### deal.cpp

```cpp
    #include "deal.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <unistd.h>

    int iFlag;

    void *run(void *arg){

      while(1){
    //        sleep(1);
        printf("%d\n", iFlag);
        printf("%d%d\n", iFlag, iFlag);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One common way is to create a slot-method and a QTimer that will call that method every so-many milliseconds, e.g.

in MainWindow.h:

```
#include <QTimer>
#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow 
{
Q_OBJECT

   [...]

private slots:
   void MySlot();

private:
   QTimer myTimer;
};
```

in MainWindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    [...]

    connect(&myTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(MySlot()));
    myTimer.start(100);   // MySlot() will be called every 100mS
}

void MainWindow::MySlot()
{
    printf("%d\n", iFlag);
}
```

Note that this approach assumes that `MySlot()` will return quickly; if it doesn't, your GUI will freeze up until it returns, since `MySlot()` is still running in the GUI thread and is therefore holding off the handling of other GUI events.  So be sure not to do anything inside `MySlot()` that takes a long time, unless you are willing to live with an not-very-responsive GUI.

Comment: Could you tell me how the code in main.cpp looks like?